# Supplying StreamField with default value in Wagtail admin interface

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

By default, wagtail's `StreamField` looks something like this in the admin for empty fields, showing the different blocks available for the user:
[image: Default view of a StreamField in the wagtail admin]

I would however prefer it to contain a block of my choosing by default. For example:

[image: A StreamField control with a single rich text block with content]

How would I accomplish this? Setting a `default` keyword argument for the field didn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you mean setting a default value on the RichTextBlock inside the StreamField?

Comment: @cssidy while that is also useful, I was referring more to setting which block spawns by default, i.e. so it doesn't start out empty with the choices open

Comment: So what you're looking for is when a user clicks the plus icon on the StreamField, a RichTextBlock is pre-selected, skipping over the banner with other block types? Or, the banner with other block types stays open and a RichTextBlock appears below?

Comment: My intention is that a user wouldn't have to click the "plus" icon and select a block at all. The field will come pre-populated with a block, and a user may add whatever other blocks they wish before/after or whatever

Comment: Can you post the code that you tried when you were setting the default? I believe the post needs a default value in the StreamField if you want its block to appear without someone opening the plus icon.

Answer (score 3):

When you tried to set a default keyword, did you set it on the RichTextBlock inside the StreamField? According to the docs, all block types accept the following optional keyword arguments: default, label, group, icon, and template. For example:

```
body = StreamField([
        ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock(default='Add you content here')),
    ])
```